# Sagemaker Sklearn Transformation Jobs not able to process parquet file

Tags: python, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I have a trained model built using sklearn container (`framework_version="0.23-1"`).
While running batchg transform job using parquet file I am getting below error:

```
 File "transform_job.py", line 47, in <module>
    content_type='application/x-parquet')
    return run_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/transformer.py", line 296, in transform
    batch_data_capture_config,
    transform_job.start(TransformInput, TransformOutput, TransformResources, **kwargs)
    if _payload_size_within_limit(buffer + element, size):
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

Code:

```
final_model = SKLearnModel(
          model_data=latest_model_data
        , role=exec_role
        , entry_point='entrypoint.py'
        , framework_version="0.23-1",
          dependencies=["constants.py"],
        )


css_transformer = final_model.transformer(instance_count=inference_instance_count
                                                  , instance_type=inference_instance_type
                                                  , output_path=output_path
                                                  , accept='application/x-parquet'
                                                  , max_payload=2
                                                  , max_concurrent_transforms=1
                                                  , strategy = 'MultiRecord'
                                                  )

css_transformer.transform(data=s3_data_partition_prefix, 
                                data_type='S3Prefix', 
                                content_type='application/x-parquet')
```

Answer (score 0):

Batch Transform does not support parquet as a splittable file format. Only `Line, RecordIO, or TFRecord`. You could use parquet with single record though.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTransformJob.html#sagemaker-CreateTransformJob-request-BatchStrategy

From the error I suspect you are using local model:
https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/cb019f6fe64bb996d0b5bb249324e4c562f00514/src/sagemaker/local/data.py#L381.

Parquet is not a supported splittable file format to create mini batches both locally and in the hosted environment.

I suggest testing with single record or use a supported splittable file format.